# iPhone lockscreen BG when recording

Tags: iphone, uikit, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder

The iPhone voice memos application changes the lock screen to something like this:

http://desmond.yfrog.com/Himg610/scaled.php?tn=0&server=610&filename=99npn.jpg&xsize=480&ysize=480

Is this possible to do with or without using private APIs? I have not found any clues on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official way to do this.